# Check in jQuery Sortable list if it is an item on root level

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#group-options). It is already possible to drag and drop items in a list on multiple levels. How do I know if the item I trying to drag and drop is on root level?

This is my current code:

```
$("#koppen_sortable").sortable({
            containerSelector: ".sortable-container",
            itemSelector: ".sortable-item",
            handle: 'i.fa-arrows',
            placeholder: '<div class="sortable-item placeholder"> </div>',
            onDrop: moveKopInDocument,
            tolerance: 6
        });

// Move the kop with the document
    var moveKopInDocument = function ($item, container, _super, event) {
        // Handle move base method first
        _super($item, container);

        // here I would like to check if this item current position is a root item or a sub item
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it as follow:

```
if($item[0].parentElement.parentElement.className !== 'sortable-item') {
            // this is a root item
        } else {
            // this is a sub item
        }
```